# I can't connect java with hive

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have installed hadoop-2.3.0 and successfully configured hive on my machine ..
i have windows 7 on my machine ..
now i 've created so simple project to just connect to hive driver ..

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Hive_java{
       private static String driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";  

       public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

       Class.forName(driver);

       Connection connect = 
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/data", "", "");   //connecting to default database
 }
}
```

and added these jars

[image]

now i have this error which can't solve it for some days .. connection refused
[image]

please tell me what can i do as am beginner in hive .. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested the port? can you see it using something like telnet? are there any messages in your hive log?

Comment: how can i test the port ?? .. i could write command but in cmd and it works fine ..

Comment: i 've searched about telnet now and open it ..
how can i use it to test the port ?

Comment: `telnet <hostname> <port number>`

Comment: How do you know you "successfully configured it"? Isn't connecting to it part of making it "successfully run"?

Comment: sorry but I said "successfully configured it" because i could write commands like create database on command line .. and data base is created and i can open it in 50070 ..

Comment: i write command " telnet localhost 10000"
but it told met "inavlid Command"

Comment: where can i find my hostname

Comment: Have a look in your system properties